# libboost 1.62 error option --log_sink

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I just install `boost 1.62` and run boost unit test option with `--log_sink=output.xml` but i got an error.

here is my command line

```
./App --log_level=test_suite --log_format=JUNIT --log_sink=output.xml
```

and i got this error message from boost

```
test setup error: Access with invalid type for argument corresponding to parameter log_sink
```

I already did unit test with `boost 1.56` there was no error with `--log_sink` and I dont know why it happened in `boost 1.62`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some`boost::test` command line options appear to be broken in `boost 1.62`, see: [Boost.test --report_sink parameter broken](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12507).

A workaround is to use the `--logger` option, e.g.:

```
./App --logger=JUNIT,test_suite,output.xml
```